# Embedding a YUI Treeview inside a menu

Tags: javascript, treeview, yui

I want to have a website navigation menu, where whenever someone clicks on it, a treeview with checkboxes appears, where they can select nodes in the tree.

Is this possible with YUI Treeview (http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/ ) or will I have to make it myself?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible. Have a look at the [Custom TreeView with Check Boxes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/treeview/tasklist.html) YUI example.